# How do I merge array of objects with array of ObjectIds into one unique list in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, aggregation

I have a few documents that looks like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('232be4e2fd568670ec11d98b'),
name: 'Discord',
type: 'A',
devices: [
    ObjectId('642be505fd568670ec11d10c'),
    ObjectId('552be45cfd568670ec30d779')
],
endpoints: [
    {
        refId: ObjectId('641316fd596514e63a2121ca')
    },
    {
        refId: ObjectId('642bd725c7e5ec334ee17ce7')
    },
    {
        refId: ObjectId('552be45cfd568670ec30d779')
    }
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('642c073643aaf70eee741e05'),
name: 'Twitter',
type: 'A',
devices: [
    ObjectId('642c072b37e4e956dfed39a0'),
    ObjectId('642c0730aa06dc1f7906b9a3')
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('642c07b2fb3917c094e30734'),
name: 'Facebook',
type: 'A'
```

I'm trying to turn this into a document with `_id` and `devices` which is an array of unique ObjectIds. And be aware that endpoints and devices can be non-existing.

The result should look like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('232be4e2fd568670ec11d98b'),
devices: [
    ObjectId('642be505fd568670ec11d10c'),
    ObjectId('552be45cfd568670ec30d779'),
    ObjectId('641316fd596514e63a2121ca'),
    ObjectId('642bd725c7e5ec334ee17ce7')
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('642c073643aaf70eee741e05'),
devices: [
    ObjectId('642c072b37e4e956dfed39a0'),
    ObjectId('642c0730aa06dc1f7906b9a3')
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('642c07b2fb3917c094e30734'),
devices: [
]
```

I have to use group, but how do I concat the two arrays into one unique array? I've tried something like this:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        endpoints: {
            $addToSet: '$endpoints.refId'
        },
        devices: {
            $push: '$devices'
        }
    }
}
```

But already here I get issues if the arrays does not exist..

Comment: can you check again

Comment: @cmgchess yep works now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `$project` stage and in that use [`$concatArrays`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/). check if field existing using [`$ifNull`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) and if it is concat an empty array otherwise concat the relevant field. Finally to make the ids unique in the devices array you can use then [`$setUnion`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#-setunion--aggregation-) operator

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      devices: {
        $setUnion: [
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$devices",
                  []
                ]
              },
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$endpoints.refId",
                  []
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g9XQ7W_vjTW)

Another approach would be to use `$setUnion` the arrays where the endpoint id only array can be achieved using a [`$map`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      devices: {
        $setUnion: [
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$devices",
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$endpoints",
                  []
                ]
              },
              as: "endpoint",
              in: "$$endpoint.refId"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f6nyDoJ8u3n)

Comment: i see i missed the unqiue part